# How can I use document.referrer with two different modals?

Tags: javascript, debugging, modal-dialog, referrer

I have two different modals on my website, one with specific domains to target, the other to target all pages with domain `website.com`. Both modals are targeting the `document.referrer` and each modal has a different id (`#closureModal` and `#parkModal`).

My issue is that the `#parkModal` is firing on all pages (rather than specific pages: `website.com/parks/park1`, `website.com/acitivies/park1`, etc) since it starts with the domain `website.com`.

**How can I allow two different modals target the `document.referrer` without one appearing where it's not meant to?** How can I use document.referrer with two different modals?

here is `#closureModal`'s code:

```
  const tsp = ["website.com"];
  const closureReferrer = document.referrer;
  const referrer_hostname = closureReferrer !== "" ? new URL(closureReferrer).hostname : "";

  if (tsp.includes(referrer_hostname)) {
    console.log("Don't Show Modal", closureReferrer);
  }  else {
    console.log("Show Modal", closureReferrer);
    $( window ).on('load', function() {
      console.log("closure modal firing");
      $('#closureModal .closure').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        show: true
      });
    });

  }
```

the `#parkModal` is similar code:

```
const domains = ["https://website.com/parks/park1", "https://website.com/parks/events/park1", "https://website.com/parks/events/park1", "https://website.com/parks/promotions/park1", "https://website.com/parks/go-green/park1", "https://website.com/parks/info/park1", "https://website.com/parks/activities/park1", "https://website.com/parks/events/park1/#/?park=park1"];
const parkReferrer = document.referrer;

if (domains.includes(parkReferrer)) {
  console.log("Don't Show Modal - from Cummins page", parkReferrer);
} else {
  console.log("Show Modal - From other Page", parkReferrer);
  $( window ).on('load', function() {
     console.log("park modal firing");
     $('#parkModal').modal({
     backdrop: 'static',
     keyboard: false,
     show: true
     });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't immediately see the issue but I do have some advice on what may help you move closer to both better code and something that is easier to diagnose.

I see a lot of code duplication. Is it necessary to have two different window `onload` events that both look at the referrer and then decide which modal to display? My recommendation is do it all in one `onload` handler that looks at `document.referrer` only once, then determines what modal to display (if any).

Something kinda like:

```
$( window ).on('load', function() {
   console.log("park modal firing");

   // define your parkReferrers and closureReferrers here
   const referrer = document.referrer;

   const displayParkReferrerModal = parkReferrers.includes(referrer);
   const displayClosureModal = closureReferrers.includes(referrer);

   let modalToDisplay;
   if (displayParkReferrerModal) {
     modalToDisplay = '#parkModal';
   } else if (displayClosureModal) {
     modalToDisplay = '#closureModal .closure';
   }

   if (modalToDisplay) {
     console.log(modalToDisplay);
     $(modalToDisplay).modal({
       backdrop: 'static',
       keyboard: false,
       show: true    
     });
     return;
   }

   console.log('no matching modal to display');
   return;     
});
```

Hope this is helpful. You could also abstract this to a handleReferrerModal function that you then invoke in the `load` event handler. That might be cleaner if you have multiple different things happening on `load`.